# How exactly does Ligo achieve complete destructive interference with just an interferometer?

Tags: visible-light, laser, interference, interferometry, ligo

Ligo works by destructively interfering light from a laser using an interferometer. Its said that no light enters the photo detector when all mirrors are the same distance. However,based on my research,the light would just create an interference pattern and never completely destructively interfere. How exactly does ligo do this? Can I get it done on a smaller scale?

Comment: Yes, it creates an interference pattern with a null on the detector.

Comment: what research ?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero
research as in researching the topic through reading. Not actual scientific research.

Comment: what readings?  It would be much easier to have the source.

Comment: A Michaelson interferometer with equal arms can be set up  so that the beam splitter sends all the light out of one port and none out of the other. Nothing mysterious in that.

Comment: @mikestone that might be the point of confusion. You *can't* do this with a standard Michelson can you? You get an interference pattern of concentric rings in both the input and output ports.

Comment: @ProfRob:  I know that with the usual setup you get rings, but with suitable design  you can presumably select only the central disc.  I think the OP imagines that you can make *all* the light go away rather than direct it to the other port.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you have read a simplified explanation of [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO). The LIGO detector works by looking at one single point in the interference pattern between the two beams. The beam optics are actively adjusted to minimise the intensity of light at this point - I imagine it is not possible to achieve zero intensity (which would require an infinitely long measuring time anyway) but they get as close as they can. Any change in light intensity at that point - or, equivalently, any change in the adjustment required to minimise light intensity - indicates a change in the beam length in one or both arms. Much of the engineering complexity of LIGO and similar detectors lies in reducing the level of noise in the apparatus to the point where gravitational waves are detectable.

Comment: I think the instrument is deliberately adjusted to be just off the null point. I would also be surprised if laser light was wasted by only measuring the intensity at a point in a Michelson-like interference pattern. Isn't the measured signal collected from the entire beam width?